# Slide Panel on Dynamically Created Images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a a slide down working on an image.  In the fiddle below it is just a div but this is replaced by an image in real case.  Please see working example:

Now, the issue I have is that if I have more than one image then this is looped:

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class="clickable_div"></div>
  <div class="nav_menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="l1"><strong>Client Name</strong></li>
            <li>Company Name</li>
            <li>Job Title</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.clickable_div').mouseover( function(){
$('.nav_menu').slideDown();
})
$('.wrap').mouseleave( function(){
$('.nav_menu').slideUp();
});

 });//]]> 


$('.clickable_div').mouseover( function(){
$('.nav_menu').slideDown();
})
$('.wrap').mouseleave( function(){
$('.nav_menu').slideUp();
});
```

This is what this achieves and it works well for 1 image: https://jsfiddle.net/r70nbL8t/1/

The issue I am facing is that say for example 5 images are in a row.  I hover over one of them then then they all slide down.  I need to attach a number for example to make them unique, the php code I am using is to loop is:

```
<table cellspacing="5">
<?php
$sessionTrainers = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *** Criteria Here");
$m = 0; // Start Counter
$n = 4; // Each Nth iteration would be a new table row
while($attendees = mysqli_fetch_array($sessionTrainers))
{

if($m % $n == 0 && $m != 0)
{
// New table row
echo '</tr><tr>';
}
$m++;
?>

    <td style="padding:5px;" align="center">
    <div class='wrap'>
    <div class="clickable_div">
    <img style="border:8px solid #3ED300;" height="150px" src="#" />
    </div>

    <div class="nav_menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="l1"><strong><? echo $attendees['NAME']; ?> <? echo $attendees['LAST_NAME']; ?></strong></li>
            <li><? echo $companyName ?></li>
            <li><? echo $attendeeJobTitle ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div></div><br /></td>
<?
}
?>
</table>
```

So what this basically does is add an image into a td until there is 4 in a row and then starts a new row and continues. Now how do I dynamically get the script to work on images when one is hovered over, only that one slide?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r70nbL8t/3/)

You need to use `$(this)`. If you use a class without context, you're targeting all the instances of the class in the DOM, instead you have to target the class which is relative to the element you're hovering onto.

```
$('.clickable_div').mouseover( function(){
    $(this).next('.nav_menu').slideDown();
})

$('.clickable_div').mouseleave( function(){
    $(this).next('.nav_menu').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help, all are sliding individually now

Comment: Bit of a different question but would you know how, when you hover over the panel that slides underneath, when your mouse is on it for it to stay open.  Currently if I hover over the main green square and go onto the grey it slides back up.

Comment: if you're able to change the html and put the `.nav_menu` inside the `.clickable_div` .. it will be easier. here is the demo for that, obviously you have to change some of the css https://jsfiddle.net/r70nbL8t/7/